# How to Login to my Chegg account with python and extract the answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to know how I can log in to my Chegg account with python without selenium then extract an exact answer to an HTML page how can I do that (I am a beginner) Please If Any Can Help me Answer me.

Comment: You have to provide some efforts and be more specific on the issue. I suggest using requests library and `.post` method. maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs) helps. also You should then know about sessions

Comment: I have a Paid Subscription from Chegg and would like to save the solutions to a few chapters for my math textbook. What I would like to do is open the link for each solution, and save that webpage as a PDF using Python 3. I was able to figure out the code to save the site as a PDF using some libraries including Requests. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to log in. without using any "complex" things like Selenium (I'm a beginner)? If you have any specific tutorial help me without or of you know I can DM You?

Comment: I already linked You to a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs), it is pretty straight forward and I suppose You have to use `.post` function but also You have to provide Your own code that deals with this matter and what has failed. also I suggest then using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k), but start with [requests](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs)